# How to enable docusign ID check for Australian user

Tags: docusignapi

Docusign ID check asked for SSN. How to enable the same for Australian users?. What is the mandatory values [ like ssn ] needs to be passed for it? Is there any documentation [ specify these data for different countries like Canada, Australia, UK]?

Answer (score 1):

In short, the current ID Check authentication is scoped to users in the United States. Other authentication options such as SMS/Phone work internationally as an alternative.